# symfony 3 - controller return on separate function generates error

Tags: php, json, symfony, controller

Just wondering why this does not work.

I am getting the error below in a controller when placing the JSON return in a separate method:

```
The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller? (500 Internal Server Error)
```

The setup is like this:

controller

```
namespace UsedBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
...
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;


class AccountController extends Controller
{
private $status;
private $message;
private $data;

/**
 * @Route("/mon-compte", name="account_page")
 */

public function showAccount(Request $request){
    $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
    if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
        throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
    }
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $email = $session->get('email');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine('doctrine')->getManager('used');
    $this->user_info = $em->getRepository('UsedBundle:User')
    ->UserAccountInfoAction( $email ); 

    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        if($_POST['action'] == 'update_user'){
            $this->updateProfile($request, $user, $form, $em);
        }elseif($_POST['action'] == 'delete_user'){
            $this->deleteUser( $user, $em );
        }elseif($_POST['action'] == 'update_password'){
            $this->updatePassword( $user, $em, $factory);
        }
               // \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($this->data);
        $this->returnJson();//***** this is generating the error*****
    }else{
        // populate change profile form
        return $this->render('account/account.html.twig', [
            'user_info' => $this->user_info,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

and then, further down on that class I have the returnJson() method:

```
    public function returnJson(){
    return new JsonResponse(array(
        'status' => $this->status, 
        'message' => $this->message,
        'data' => $this->data,
        )
    );         
}
```

If I place that code replacing the $this->returnJson() on showAccount(), it will work correctly.

Any ideas why the return can't be placed as a separate method? Or am I missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `returnJson` function returns `JsonResponse` into `showAccount` function, not out of it.

This should work:

```
return $this->returnJson();
```

Comment: Thanks @svgrafov, that was it!